# Do all clone troopers have names?

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars

Or have some failed to achieve individuality and remained as literally just a number?

Comment: It would appear that they **all** name themselves and each other, often based on their roles/serial numbers; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clone_trooper

Comment: I think the answer may depend on what your question means. Not all troopers have a name at any given time but presumably receive one eventually as they develop character traits that set them apart. "Do all clone troopers at any given time have names?" is a different than "Do all clone troopers eventually receive names?"

Comment: Canon only or Legends too?

Comment: While I don't know of any examples off the top of my head, it's easy to assume that it's completely possible for clones to have died as a cadet or early in their career before earning a nickname. The Clone Wars S03E01 "Clone Cadets" is a good canon source for my line of thinking.

Comment: hmm, I think my context refers to all clones by the time the concept of named clone troopers introduced by the Jedi became the norm. As we can see, troopers like Fives and Heavy got their names while still a cadet.

Answer (score 4):

## No

While most of the clone trooper characters we know about (i.e. who aren't just scene "extras") have names, there is a selection bias: if such a character is notable enough to be more than a mere "extra" then he's probably notable enough to get a nickname.

I suspect many (perhaps the majority) of clones were never given a nickname, especially those who died early in the war. All the clones who died in the Battle of Geonosis, for example, probably did not have time to earn a nickname.

The following are examples of clones without names:

#### Canon

[Clone 99](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/99) is a clone who was never given a nickname. He didn't serve in the war, either, because he was malformed and had genetic defects.

[image]

[CT-327](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/CT-327) is another possibility. He was ambushed by Separatist droids, but the [transcript of the episode he appeared in](http://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=star-wars-the-clone-wars&episode=s01e05) has another clone refer to him by his numerical designation when he could have used a nickname:

> CT-327, report in.

[CT-1477](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/CT-1477) is yet another possibility. He is only referred to by his numerical designation in the [transcript of the episode he appeared in](http://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=star-wars-the-clone-wars&episode=s02e20):

> Copy that, CT-1477....CT-1477, report in. CT-1477, why have you broken off transmission?

#### Legends

The [(archived) "clone troopers" article on starwars.com](https://web.archive.org/web/20110903091200/http://www.starwars.com/databank/organization/clonetroopers/index.html) mentions in the "From the Expanded Universe" section that

> Clone troopers typically refer to each other by their identification numbers. In small groups and under close quarters conditions, they commonly refer to each other using only the last two digits of their ID number. The use of individualized nicknames was known to occur on the battlefield, but the Kaminoans disparaged the asymmetry it introduced among their creations. At the behest of the Republic and the Jedi, the cloners put aside their dislike for Alpha's program that resulted in such notable named clone soldiers as Odd Ball, Cody, Bacara, Bly, Neyo, Appo, Fox and Gree.

There are quite a few unnamed clones from Legends, in part due to the Kaminoans' discouragement of names. A notable example is [CT-915](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/CT-915), whose death was lamented by CT-914. CT-914 referred to him by his numerical designation despite being close to him. Another notable example is [CC-4816](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/CC-4816) -- whereas all the aforementioned clones were mere troopers, CC-4816 was a clone *commander* yet no name for him is known.

Comment: "All the clones who died in the Battle of Geonosis, for example, probably did not have time to earn a nickname."

This is the only dubious statement in this answer, I think - those clones may not have fought long, but they had years to grow up and train together before that.

Comment: @recognizer The Kaminoans would have discouraged the use of nicknames while the clones were growing up and training together. It's only when the clones left Kamino and bonded together (on the battlefield, with each other and the Jedi) that they had a chance to get a nickname.

Comment: How much more intuitive and easier to say is "Rex" than "CT-7567"? I reckon these clones are going to have developed nicknames for one another pretty quick.